# Facebook OpenGraph Object custom image

Tags: facebook, facebook-opengraph

i can pass custom params via actions to objects, and retrieve it in the aggregator. I see that i can also specify custom properties in this object : but how can i pass params to it?

for example , having an object like this :

```
<meta property="fb:app_id" content="APPID" />
<meta property="og:type"   content="myapp:myobject" />
<meta property="og:url"  content="http://www.myabsolutepath.to/object.html" />
<meta property="og:title"  content="OBJECT TITLE" />
<meta property="og:image"  content="http://www.myabsolutepath.to/img.jpg" />
<meta property="myobject:myimage"  content="{some dynamic content}" />
```

how can i pass values to the prop myobject:myimage , and show it in aggregator ?

For example , in Pinterest , when i Pin a board, in both pop-up description in ticker,feed and in aggregator i see custom images.

I tried with .php objects , but if i pass GET params to them, the params shown is always the default.

Hope my question is clear,
Thanks in advance!

EDIT: Solved, thanks to this blog post. https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/usergeneratedphotos/
as you can see, no url parameters are required to change og:image , but post params to add an og:image array to the action ... bacause they are not parsed(by my tests) when generating open graph stories in timeline and ticker.

Comment: I don't understand, you set the image with the `og:image` tag as you did, how can you customize it more?

Comment: i want to have a single Object in which i can pass and display custom params. Like Pinterest do.

Answer (score 0):

You need to output this html content via a dynamic url on your server, such as using php or any other server side language.

Then, the in the url of the object you can dd parameters (`http://www.example.com/object?id=453`), either by querystring or using pretty urls (`http://www.example.com/object/453`).

The problem is that facebook cache the results for a given url, so you can't have the same url outputting different content for the same parameters since the first response will be cached.

Comment: I wrote a php Object with GET params switch, but it seems that aggregators not only cache results, but they can't pass params to the object. There must be a way, cause i want to achive a Pinterest like effect (in the aggregator, custo image and title). Is quite simple to pass String vars with the action and display them, there must be another way to display custom img's.

Comment: I don't use pinterest so I don't really understand what you're trying to accomplish, maybe you can try to explain? (if it's long just edit your original question)

Comment: edit above, hope is more clear .... pinterest is the only app i see using OG this way, i don't have any other examples

Comment: All OG objects are defined by a url, in that url you can specify what ever image you'd like. So, let's say one object is `http://example.com/obj?id=5` and the other is `http://example.com/obj?id=43`, each of the urls will output different `og:image` value. Is that what you want?

Comment: is what i can achieve .... but is not what it works. cause, in the end, objects seems to be cached as http://example.com/obj , without any params . @Nitzan : i think you are missing the 'how show custom image in aggregator' part of the question, i'll prepare a sample app to illustrate what i want to say.

Comment: Fine, prepare the sample app, but you're wrong. Objects are not cached without the query string parameters. Facebook indexes/caches the web by the urls, including all parts of the url.

Comment: yes but in object definition inside the opengraph Dashboard, i have to give a signle URL per object. Then, even if i add as much params as i can, the object shown in the aggregator will reflect that single URL only. For example, if i want to pass custom string to my aggregator, have to do something like /me/[APP]:[ACTION]?[OBJ]=[OBJURL]?[CUSTOM PROP]=xxxx. then, in aggregator definition, i will show [CUSTOM PROP] referencig it as {CUSTOM PROP}. Can't get the same thing work for images.

Comment: Where in the object definition do you need to supply an object url? Only when posting an action do you need to supply the url of the object. In this context objects are like classes (in oop), and the urls are like object instances.

Comment: when you define an aggregator, you need to include your url.(in the form of http://samples.ogp.me/xxxxx). this became THE object definition. You get this url debugging your custom URL ...and you need to pass again it with JS's post actions (dont'k know if i need it with CURL).

Comment: No, you do not. Where in the [Define Aggregations documentation](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/define-units/) do you see that? Even when searching the document for the word `url` you'll get 0 matches. What is it that you're talking about?

Comment: anyway .... this is what i want achieve : https://www.socialnetworkserver.it/davide_tests/pinterest-aggregator.jpg ...as you can see, one object, different images. for both objects(board and users)

Comment: For my experience, that document is really lacking. I NEVER was able to submit an action for approval, if i didn't associates sample.ogp.me url and object. Always getting errors ... did you complete an action approval, only with that documentation? But this is off topic.

Comment: That's not the same object. It might be the same object definition, but not the same instance. Again: let's say you have an object album, and the base url is: `http://example.com/album`. Then each object instance will have a different url, i.e.: `http://example.com/album?id=3` or `http://example.com/album/3`, and the out put of each one will have different values in the og tags. **Follow** the docs, those are right.

Comment: yes but i started the discussion because this method dont works. Try it. the 'id=number' are not passed to object in the aggregators.Did you have success with the method you are suggesting? if yes, can you share code? cause by my side, this method don't seems to work. Maybe i'm mistaking something.

Comment: and, bacause OG not approved are visible only to admins, can you send me a friend requst on FB? I'll make you admin of a sample app i'll put online this evening, so you'll can test directly.